# gridsearch.predict_proba results in list rather than array

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest, roc, gridsearchcv

I followed [example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html) and tried to use gridsearch with a random forest classifier to generate roc_auc_score, however, the y_prob=model.predict_proba(X_test)
I generated was in list (two arrays) rather than one. So I was wondering what went wrong here.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import label_binarize
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, StratifiedShuffleSplit
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score

X = np.random.rand(50,10)
y = np.random.permutation([1] * 25 + [0] * 25)

y= label_binarize(y, classes=[0, 1])
y= np.hstack((1-y, y))

sss = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, test_size=0.2, random_state=7)  
index_split = sss.split(X, y)
train_index = []
test_index = []
for train_ind, test_ind in index_split:
train_index.extend(train_ind)
test_index.extend(test_ind)

data_train = X[train_index]
out_train = y[train_index]
data_test = X[test_index]
out_test = y[test_index]

rf = RandomForestClassifier()
grids = {
     'n_estimators': [10, 50, 100, 200],   
     'max_features': ['auto', 'sqrt', 'log2'], 
     'criterion': ['gini', 'entropy']
        }
rf_grids_searched = GridSearchCV(rf, 
                                grids, 
                                scoring = "roc_auc",
                                n_jobs = -1,
                                refit=True,
                                cv = 5,
                                verbose=10)

rf_grids_searched.fit(data_train, out_train)
rf_best = rf_grids_searched.best_estimator_

y_prob=rf_best.predict_proba(data_test)
print(roc_auc_score(out_test, y_prob))
```

my result:

```
array([[0.5, 0.5],
    [0.5, 0.5],
    [0.7, 0.3],
    [0.3, 0.7],
    [0.7, 0.3],
    [0.5, 0.5],
    [0.1, 0.9],
    [0.6, 0.4],
    [0.6, 0.4],
    [0.4, 0.6]]), array([[0.5, 0.5],
    [0.5, 0.5],
    [0.3, 0.7],
    [0.7, 0.3],
    [0.3, 0.7],
    [0.5, 0.5],
    [0.9, 0.1],
    [0.4, 0.6],
    [0.4, 0.6],
    [0.6, 0.4]])]
```

expected results with probability of [0,1]:

```
    array([[0.5, 0.5],
    [0.5, 0.5],
    [0.7, 0.3],
    [0.3, 0.7],
    [0.7, 0.3],
    [0.5, 0.5],
    [0.1, 0.9],
    [0.6, 0.4],
    [0.6, 0.4],
```

I also tried not to binarize y in the first place and then train gridsearch to get the following array y_prob. Later, I binarize y_test to match the dimension of y_prob and get the score. I was wondering if the sequence is correct?
code:

```
  out_test1= label_binarize(out_test, classes=[0, 1])
  out_test1= np.hstack((1-out_test1, out_test1))
  print(roc_auc_score(out_test1, y_prob))   

   array([[0.6, 0.4],
   [0.5, 0.5],
   [0.6, 0.4],
   [0.5, 0.5],
   [0.7, 0.3],
   [0.3, 0.7],
   [0.8, 0.2],
   [0.4, 0.6],
   [0.8, 0.2],
   [0.4, 0.6]])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grid search's `predict_proba` method is just a dispatch to the best estimator's `predict_proba`.  And from [the docstring](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.predict_proba) for `RandomForestClassifier.predict_proba` (emphasis added):

> Returns
>
> p : ndarray of shape (n_samples, n_classes), **or a list of n_outputs
> such arrays if n_outputs > 1**. ...

Since you've specified two outputs (two columns in `y`), you get predicted probabilities for each of the two classes *for each* of the two targets.

Comment: Thanks. I also tried not to binarize y in the first place and then train gridsearch to get the following array y_prob. Later, I binarize y_test to match the dimension of y_prob to get the score. But I was wondering if the roc_auc_score is correct in this way? The results in attached in the post

Comment: Normally, don't binarize, and pull the second column from `predict_proba` for use in the auc score.

Comment: print(roc_auc_score(out_test, y_prob[:, 1]))=0.48? Does it mean the predictive probability for class 1 is 0.48? Though the data is hypothetical, can the predicative probability of roc < 0.5?

Comment: That looks right, yes. A random classifier has auc 0.5, but that's asymptotic; for your small example it's not unreasonable to end up slightly above or below.